# spring boot query , what's wrong with this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get data from db based on multiple conditions and I'm getting exception error:
   "The string  starts a quoted range at 69, but never ends it"

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (u.name = ?1 and u.status= ?2)")
List<User> findUsers(String name, String status);

//at controller

@GetMapping("active")
    public List<User> findUsers()
    {
        String name= "Ali";
        String status = "ACT";
        return repository.findUsers(name, status);
    }
```

Comment: Add your repository method where you used this

Comment: See this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query
For you case I would use named query like this findAllByNameAndStatus(String name, String status)

Answer (score 1):

You parameter are not mapping properly.
Map the parameter using `@Param`

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (u.name = :name and u.status= :status)")
List<User> findUsers(@Param("name") String name, @Param("status") String status);
```

Or

Use the order of method parameters in the method declaration

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (u.name = ?1 and u.status= ?2)")
List<User> findUsers(String name, String status);
```